# unable to list data using flatlist

Tags: react-native, axios, expo, react-native-flatlist, react-native-elements

i am trying to list an array that i fetched from an api using FlatList but its not displaying any contents.i cross checked the array it had elements when i printed it.

so in flatlist component i suspect the issue lies at renderItem prop.

```
state = {bookData:[]}

  componentWillMount ()
  {
axios.get('https://udhishtabharata.com/appsupport/alanwattsapp/services/ list/book///id')
       .then(response => this.setState({bookData: response.data}))
   }
 renderdata(){
   {console.log(this.state.bookData)}
 }

 render(){
     return (
      <View style={styles.viewStyles}>
      <View style={styles.statusBarStyle} />
      <Header headerText='Books' />
      {this.renderdata()}
      <List>
        <FlatList>
            data={this.state.bookData}

            renderItem={({item})=> (
              <ListItem 
                roundAvatar
                title={item.title}

              />
            )}
        </FlatList>
      </List>

  </View>
);
}
}
```

and my response is :

```
[
  {
    "id":"32",
    "title":"Become What You Are",
    "subtitle":"",
    "photo":"/files/pictures/book/32-5.jpg",
    "url":"https://www.amazon.com/Become-What-You-Alan-Watts/dp/1570629404",
    "metakeywords":"Alan Watts Book: Become What You Are",
    "metadescr":"The book Become what you are published in 1957 presents Alan Watts’ meditations and reflections on the dilemma of capturing the true self. ",
    "metatitle":"Alan Watts Book: Become What You Are",
    "doa":"2018-11-20 12:13:31",
    "dou":"2018-11-20 12:31:39",
    "descr":"<div>The book 'Become what you are' published in 1957 presents Alan Watts’ meditations and reflections on the dilemma of capturing the true self. Become what you are exposes the playfulness and intelligence of thought and simplicity of language that has made him famous as an exponent of Eastern thoughts for Westerners. <br></div><div><br></div><div>\r\nIn the book, he discusses various philosophical ideas and offers practical wisdom of the life of human beings. He rejects the thought of ego which is to be avoided but is unavoidable in every aspect of life. Changing the nature of life is the root of this work. It gives a lively effect on your mind and examines how the reality works in several aspects and variants of life situations. It gives the basic knowledge on Zen and Tao from which the detailed idea of wisdom is understood. The whole concept revolves around seeing life as it is which is the taoist notion of joyful living.</div>",
    "views":"0",
    "outboundlinkclick":"0",
    "urlname":"become_what_you_are",
    "status":"A",
    "customer_name":"",
    "customer_photo":""
  },
  {
    "id":"35",
    "title":"The Way of Zen",
    "subtitle":"",
    "photo":"/files/pictures/book/35-2.jpg",
    "url":"https://www.amazon.com/Way-Zen-Alan-W-Watts/dp/0375705104",
    "metakeywords":"",
    "metadescr":"",
    "metatitle":"",
    "doa":"2018-11-20 12:39:57",
    "dou":"2018-11-20 12:50:00",
    "descr":"<div>The Way of Zen is a clear-cut presentation of Zen Buddhism which is published in 1957. Alan Watts examines and explains the concepts, notions and principles of ancient religion to the Western world. The book gives a complete clarification of Zen Buddhism which has a massive difference from the Southern Indian Buddhism.</div><div>The Way of Zen is completely a non-fiction book, which is divided in to two sections. The first part deals with historical development of Zen Buddhism and second part gives a clear idea on the principles of the same. Alan traces the birth of Zen Buddhism in relation to Chinese Taoism and Mahayana Buddhism. The work also introduces a variety of philosophical concepts such as The Middle Way, anatman and wuwei. Watts, through The Way of Zen gives a clarity of thought on the ways of liberation followed by Zen Buddhism and how it is easily adapted in our lives to lead a quality life.</div>",
    "views":"0",
    "outboundlinkclick":"0",
    "urlname":"the_way_of_zen",
    "status":"A",
    "customer_name":"",
    "customer_photo":""
  }
]
```

i need the list to be shown on the screen. any help is appreciated

Comment: can you paste your response here ?

Comment: i have added my response

Comment: are you using react-native-element? for list and listitem ?

Comment: yes i am using list and listitems from react-native-elements

Comment: i think there is something missing in styling or linking so your list would not appearing

Comment: why are you using both list and flatlist ?

Comment: do u think item is the correct object for renderItem prop or it can be any variable?

Comment: i am anewbie in react native and i wanted to try flatlist so i saw a tutorial in which they use both list and flatList

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187177/discussion-between-hardik-virani-and-vishnu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to make order in your code I found some mistakes or bad usages

```
state = {
    bookData:[]
}

componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('https://udhishtabharata.com/appsupport/alanwattsapp/services/ list/book///id')
    .then(response => this.setState({bookData: response.data}))
}

render(){
    return (
        <View style={styles.viewStyles}>
            <View style={styles.statusBarStyle} />
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.bookData}
                renderItem={({item})=> 
                    <ListItem 
                    roundAvatar
                    title={item.title}
                    />
                }
                extraData={this.state.bookData}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                ListHeaderComponent={<Header headerText='Books' />}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

- Prefer `componentDidMount()` instead of `componentWillMount()` as place where to fetch data and set your state
- You can easily use just `FlatList`
- Care the way you declare `Flatlist` (you placed close tag `>` wrongly)
- Pass `FlatList` a `ListHeaderComponent` prop if you want it to scroll with your list

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one!**

```
 state = {bookData:[]}

  componentWillMount ()
  {
      axios.get('https://udhishtabharata.com/appsupport/alanwattsapp/services/ list/book///id')
       .then(response => this.setState({bookData: response.data}))
  }

 renderdata(){
   {console.log(this.state.bookData)}
 }

renderItems = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
        <View key={index}>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Image source={} />
                </TouchableOpacity> 
        </View>
    )
};

_keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

 render(){
     return (
      <View style={styles.viewStyles}>
      <View style={styles.statusBarStyle} />
      <Header headerText='Books' />
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.bookData}
            keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
            renderItem={this.renderItems}
              />

  </View>
);
}
```

Please do you styling in renderItem function
In renderItem function you are getting one by one object so according to your design make styling change and display data